# Dynamic user-triggered Angular component transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

What I'm trying to do is very simple: I have a component called `parent-component` which is setup to transclude.

```
let parentComponent = { controller: ParentComponent, template: view, transclude: true };
```

In the template for this component, I have only: `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>`

What I'd like to do is transclude other developed components dynamically based on user-triggered events. So, let's say I have another component called `transcluded-component` that I only want transcluded into `parent-component` once a button is clicked.

How do I do this? I've not had any luck using `element.append` or similar. What am I missing, here?

Comment: Did you `$compile` the component after appending it?

Comment: Use the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to programmatically add other components to the template.